# Set CheckBox Control dim as a UserForm CheckBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a class module that builds on top of a checkbox control. Within the Class Module I want to point at the checkbox in the userform. Although, when I try to fill the CheckBox object with one of the checkboxes in the userform I get a type-mismatch since calling on the checkbox gives back it's state instead of the entire object. Is there a way to get the entire object?

I have tried

```
set myCheckBox = makeMyCheckBox(Me.CheckBox1)
```

and

```
set myCheckBox = makeMyCheckBox(Me.CheckBox1.Object)
```

where makeMyCheckBox is a function that takes in a CheckBox object and creates a new MyCheckBox object.

```
'Within my userform's code

Dim myCheckBoxes(1 to 2) As MyCheckBox 'MyCheckBox is my class module

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
set myCheckBoxes(1) = makeMyCheckBox(me.CheckBox1)'<--Error Type Mismatch
End Sub

Private Function makeMyCheckBox(c As CheckBox) As MyCheckBox 
Dim myChck As MyCheckBox 
Set myChck = New MyCheckBox 
myChck.init c 'takes in a CheckBox and fills its internal CheckBox object
Set makeMyCheckBox= myChck 
End Function
```

I expect Me.CheckBox1 to be a CheckBox object.
Me.CheckBox1 outputs the checkbox's state when I look in debug (true/false)

I get--
Run-time error '13':
Type Mismatch

Comment: Qualify the types with the library they're from. `Private Function makeMyCheckBox(ByVal c As MSForms.CheckBox) As MyCheckBox` -- otherwise `As CheckBox` is `As Excel.CheckBox`, which is indeed a different and incompatible type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get a type-mismatch since calling on the checkbox gives back it's state instead of the entire object. Is there a way to get the entire object?

Wrong assumption, you're getting the "entire object", but the object you're getting isn't implementing the interface you're expecting, hence the *type mismatch*.

You need to qualify your MSForms types explicitly with the `MSForms` library, like this:

```
Private Function makeMyCheckBox(ByVal c As MSForms.CheckBox) As MyCheckBox
```

Otherwise the unqualified `CheckBox` identifier / type name is referring to `Excel.CheckBox`, because the host application's object model (the `Excel` library) always has a higher priority than the referenced `MSForms` library, in the *project references* dialog:

[image: Microsoft Excel 16.0 object library showing before Microsoft Forms 2.0 object library]

This is excruciatingly hard to discover in a vanilla VBE. With [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) you just place the caret on `CheckBox` and it tells you where it's coming from:

[image: Excel checkbox]

[image: MSForms checkbox]

Without any add-ins, you kind of have to *guess* what the actual type is, because <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (which normally takes you to the definition in the *Object Browser*) is useless for this - all you get is a message saying "the identifier under the cursor is not recognized".

> Disclaimer: I manage the Rubberduck open-source project.